# Proper way to optimize CSS 3 animations for iOS/Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, webkit, css-animations

I'm building an iPad app using PhoneGap. I'm trying to use CSS transformations for the animation, but I'm not entirely sure I'm using the proper methods to leverage any hardware acceleration the device might support.

It's a modal window (DIV) that I want to slide down from the top of the page. It'd start positioned off the top of the screen, then animated into the page itself via adding a class via jquery:

```
.modal {
      background: url('../images/bgnd-modal.png');
      width: 800px;
      height: 568px;
      position: absolute; 
      top: -618px;
      left: 100px;
      z-index: 1001;
      -webkit-transition: top .25s ease-in; 
  }
.modal.modalOn {
      top: 80px;
  }
```

When deployed onto the iPad 2 with iOS 4, this works, but the animation is slightly jerky. It's not an entirely smooth animation. Should I be using different CSS to handle this? Or is this perhaps just a side-effect of it being a PhoneGap app and the DIV in question having a large background image?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should at minimum add an empty translate3d declaration:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This will help performance immensely on iOS, as demonstrated by [Remy Sharp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKl78ZgJzm4), because it causes iOS to use hardware-acceleration.

If you want to go further, refactor the animation to use a webkit translation transform, rather than animating the 'top' property. In the transform3d property, the second parameter is the Y value. In your example, change the `-webkit-transition` to focus on the transform property, rather than top. Then, set an initial `webkit-transform` of `translate3d(0,0,0)`.

To perform your animation, change your class `.modal.modalOn` declaration to:

```
transform: translate3d(0,80px,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,80px,0)
```

This will cause iOS to animate the transform of the element, and should be even smoother, than the first method.

-- Note --
Don't forget to add a unit of measurement like px or em — something like `transform: translate3d(0,80,0);` won't work.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason not to, you can generally just make your `-webkit-transition:` apply to `all`, rather than a specific property. (And if you leave it out entirely, `all` is implied.)

Comment: Is there any harm in adding hardware acceleration to every element using this rule? `* {-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}` . When would you *not* want hardware acceleration?

Comment: I feel it's worth mentioning that -webkit-transform isn't a swiss army knife. In my tests, constant use of it when you aren't animating/manipulating elements results in heavy memory usage and flickering.

Comment: 4 years later, is this `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` still a valid solution? Cause for me I don't notice any difference.

Comment: is there anyway to apply a timing function to `transform: translateX(-13rem)` for example? The transform happens much faster on iPhone using your suggestion, but I want to add a timing function.

Comment: clankill3r: another year and a half later, it actually did solve my issue. So it my case YES, still a valid solution.

Comment: @chovy - Yes, you want to then transition the transform: ```transition: transform 100ms;```

Answer (score 3):

try adding :

```
webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: This didn't do a thing for me, on a simple change to the `left` coordinate. But the `translate3d` did the trick. (That said, I have heard other people say that there are certain properties that imply 3d and thus have the effect we're going for. But backface-visibility doesn't seem to be one of them, at least not in iOS 6.)

Comment: It has nothing to the with smooth animation.

Comment: It only adds freezes and lags.