# Smooth translation on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make 3D layer effect like on this page:
Example Page:
http://cloudraiders.com/

I did almost everything, but have one big problem that can't handle:

```
$("#mainView").mousemove(function( event ) {
  //getting mouse dimentions
  var pageX = event.pageX;
  var pageY = event.pageY;
  var mainWidth = $(this).width();
  var mainHeight = $(this).height();
  //
  //console.log(pageX);
  ("#mainView").find("li").each(function( index ) {             
    var depth = $(this).attr("dataDepth");
    var scalable = $(this).attr("scalable");
    var x = pageX*depth;
    var y = pageY*depth;
    var z = 0;      
    var thisScale = mainWidth / mainHeight * 1;
    //setting accelerated webkit transform                  
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d("+x+"%,"+y+"%,"+z+"px"+")");                  
    });
});
```

The problem is, that translate3d is not smooth like in example page. It is jumping.
When I'm moving mouse out of the window, and then enter in different place it is just jumping.

I'v found some solution in forum already, but didn't work to good with mouse move.
Any help will be a lot appreciated.

Regards!

EDIT:
I'v used Jquery animate function:

```
$(this).animate({ whyNotToUseANonExistingProperty: 100 }, {
  step: function(now,fx) {
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform',"translate3d("+x+"%,"+y+"%,"+z+"px"+")");
},
  duration:100
},'linear');
```

It works almost good, but the problem is, that Jquery is stacking queries. And if I will move mouse alot, animations goes on like for minute.

Comment: Your script don't "smooth" the transition if mouse get out/in.Keep values in some vars and try moving from old to new step by step. Also,transition: all... it may not work, you use 3d transition, not 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with css animation/transformation, there is some performance trickt bear in mind. one of them is to set a default transform value (set to 0) in order to enable the rendering those element by default.

Try addind those rule as default in your css to your animated element ("li" in your case):

```
         transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Also, note that the website linked in your answer use the [jquery parallax plugin](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/), which take care of those accelerations issues for you.

And here some ressource about css transform/animation acceleration:

[Increase Your Site’s Performance with Hardware-Accelerated CSS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

[DOM, HTML5, & CSS3 Performance](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/dom-html5-css3-performance/)

[Related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481894/proper-way-to-optimize-css-3-animations-for-ios-mobile-safari)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax, this parralax plugin just works great! And using trasition with acceleration. Not just simple top,left like other parallax plugin I'v tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect soft transition you should tell it somewhere to the browser. Just add this style and customize it. Do it in the style-sheet not inside your evented JavaScript. Handle all the prefixes.

```
#mainView{
   transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :) I'v tried this already, it's not working good with mousemove. Need some scripts.